# How to expose included private methods as public class methods?

Tags: ruby, module

I am attempting to make a module that extends the functionality of the `FileUtils` class.

```
require 'fileutils'

module FileManager
  extend FileUtils
end

puts FileManager.pwd
```

if I run this, I'll get a `private method 'pwd' called for FileManager:Module (NoMethodError)`
 error

**Update:**
Why are these class methods included privately and how can I expose **all of** them **without having to manually include each method** as public class methods in the FileManager module?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662722/extending-a-ruby-module-in-another-module-including-the-module-methods

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655623/ruby-class-c-includes-module-m-including-module-n-in-m-does-not-affect-c-what

Comment: Thanks Robert, I've seen the `included` pattern before, but since `FileUtils` didn't have a `ClassMethods` type module in it, I figured it wouldn't be plausible here. The second link looks like it might have something closer to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the instance methods on `FileUtils` are all private (as mentioned in another answer here, that means they can only be called without an explicit receiver). And what you get when you include or extend is the instance methods. For example:

```
require 'fileutils'

class A
  include FileUtils
end
A.new.pwd #=> NoMethodError: private method `pwd' called for #<A:0x0000000150e5a0>

o = Object.new
o.extend FileUtils
o.pwd #=> NoMethodError: private method `pwd' called for #<Object:0x00000001514068>
```

It turns out all the methods we want on `FileUtils` are there twice, as private instance methods and also as public *class methods* (aka singleton methods).

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4662934/1535283) I came up with this code which basically copies all the class methods from `FileUtils` to `FileManager`:

```
require 'fileutils'

module FileManager
  class << self
    FileUtils.singleton_methods.each do |m|
      define_method m, FileUtils.method(m).to_proc
    end
  end
end

FileManager.pwd #=> "/home/scott"
```

It's not pretty, but it does the job (as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'fileutils'

module FileManager
  extend FileUtils

  def FMpwd
    pwd 
  end 

  module_function :FMpwd
end

puts FileManager.FMpwd

=> /home/rjuneja/Programs/stackoverflow
```

This is partly because Ruby treats private and protected methods slightly different than other languages. When a method is declared private in Ruby, it means this method can never be called with an explicit receiver. Any time we're able to call a private method with an implicit receiver it will always succeed. You can find more information here:

http://www.skorks.com/2010/04/ruby-access-control-are-private-and-protected-methods-only-a-guideline/

Why not monkey patch FileUtils to include the methods you want instead:

```
require 'fileutils'

module FileUtils
  class << self
    def sayHello
      puts "Hello World!"
    end 
  end 
end

FileUtils.sayHello
=> "Hello World!"
```

Comment: This would require him to do that with each of FileUtils' methods which seems tedious, even with a simple iteration. Though I do like the explanation for why it happens.

Comment: McMullins, why not extend the FileUtils class instead? Check my update.